# What naming conventions should I use on the second integer on a nested for loop?

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm pretty new to programming, and I was just wondering in the following case what would be an appropriate name for the second integer I use in this piece of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
    //stuff
    }
}
```

I usually just name it x but I have a feeling that this could get confusing quickly. Is there a standard name for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending upon what you're iterating over, a name might be easy or obvious by context:

```
for(struct mail *mail=inbox->start; mail ; mailid++) {
    for (struct attachment *att=mail->attachment[0]; att; att++) {
        /* work on all attachments on all mails */
    }
}
```

For the cases where `i` makes the most sense for an outer loop variable, convention uses `j`, `k`, `l`, and so on.

But when you start nesting, look harder for meaningful names. You'll thank yourself in six months.

Answer (score 1):

You could opt to reduce the nesting by making a method call. Inside of this method, you would be using a local variable also named `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    methodCall(array[i], array);
}
```

I have assumed you need to pass the element at position `i` in the outer loop as well as the array to be iterated over in the inner loop - this is an assumption as you may actually require different arguments.

As always, you should measure the performance of this - there shouldn't be a massive overhead in making a method call within a loop, but this depends on the language.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel that you should give variables meaningful names - here `i` and `x` mean nothing and will not help you understand your code in 3 months time, at which point it will appear to you as code written by a dyslexic monkey.

Name variables so that other people can understand what your code is trying to accomplish. You will save yourself time in the long run.

Comment: I was under the impression that i was the standard thing for a for loop. I guess I was wrong about that. Thanks!

Comment: I think that it really is a defacto standard - I've seen it used in many programming books and online tutorials, and it's fine for teaching / learning how to use for loops. In production though, I feel code clarity is more important.

Comment: Why, `i` and `j` are meaningful names. The meaning is `first/outer loop index` and `second/inner loop index`

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are beginning, I'd say it's beneficial to experiment with multiple styles.

For the purposes of your example, my suggestion is simply replace `x` with `j`.
There's tons of real code that will use the convention of i, j, and k for single letter nested loop variables.

There's also tons that uses longer more meaningful names.

But there's much less that looks like your example.

So you can consider it a step forward because you're code looks more like real world code.